# c# socket always EndConnection with the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets

I use MSDN async sample to write an Async socket Client and Server class, 3000 GB data all success transferred under single client and single data send thread test. 
But when I use a for loop to create several threads to send data to server, I found that in Client side, the thread created for BeginConnectCallback were always have the same id.
and all ManualResetEvent mechanism failed, all threads actived when `ManualResetEvent.Set( )` called by first thread. (each thread has it's own ManualResetEvent object)

Here is my Client side Log sample: ( the problem is why it always Thread 7 do the EndConnect job? )

> 15:33:05.100 Data send Thread 1, BeginConnect to Server 192.168.1.100
>   Port 6000
>  15:33:05.100 Data send Thread 2, BeginConnect to Server
>   192.168.1.100 Port 6000
>  15:33:05.100 Data send Thread 3, BeginConnect to Server 192.168.1.100 Port 6000
>  15:33:05.102
>   ConnectionCallback Thread 7 Execute EndConnect and mreConnectDone.Set(
>   );
>  15:33:05.102 ConnectionCallback Thread 7 Execute EndConnect
>   and mreConnectDone.Set( );
>  15:33:05.121 Data send Thread 1,
>   Connected via Port 2650, Socket Handle: 8234
>  15:33:05.145
>   ConnectionCallback Thread 7 Execute EndConnect and mreConnectDone.Set(
>   );
>  15:33:05.170 Data send Thread 2, Connected via Port 2651,
>   Socket Handle: 8235
>  15:33:05.177 Data send Thread 3, Connected
>   via Port 2652, Socket Handle: 8236

I can mail you source code if you interested on this.
my mail is thlin.harcon@gmail.com

the [MSDN sample URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't mail source code - post the *relevant* part you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why it always Thread 7 do the EndConnect job?

`ConnectCallback` method is called by .NET Framework on a thread from the Thread Pool. If the Thread 7 is not occupied in any work at given moment then the Thread Pool manager may decide to run a callback on that thread. It's a normal behavior of the Thread Pool when all your callbacks are executed on that single thread.

If you want to notify the thread that called `BeginConnect` then you need to pass something to `BeginConnect` as the last parameter `Object state`. For example you can pass the corresponding `ManualResetEvent` object and then signal it from the callback method.

BTW, the MSDN sample you mentioned shows an example how you can retrieve the `ManualResetEvent` object (or any other object you passed to `BeginConnect`) in the callback method:

```
    // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
    Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
```